# How to avoid big memory allocation with std::make_shared

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management

Let's say that I have some arbitrary class, A:

```
class A {
 //... stuff
};
```

I want to call into an external API that takes in a shared pointer to some type, like so (**I cannot change this interface**):

```
//...much later
void foo(std::shared_ptr<A> _a){
    //operate on _a as a shared_ptr
}
```

However, in the (legacy) code I'm working with, the class `A` instance I'm working with is allocated on the stack (**which I cannot get around**):

```
A a;
//...some stuff on a
//Now time to call foo
```

On top of this, an instance of class A is quite large, on the order of 1 GB per instance.

I know I could call

```
foo(std::make_shared<A> a);
```

but that would allocate memory for a copy of A, which I would really like to avoid.

### Question

Is there a way to hack together some call to `std::make_shared` (possibly with `move` semantics) so that I am not forced to allocate memory for another instance of class A?

I've tried something like this:

```
foo(std::make_shared<A>(std::move(a)));
```

But from what I can tell, a new instance of `A` is still created.

#### Example code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;


class A{
    public:
    A(int _var=42) : var(_var){cout << "Default" << endl;}
    A(const A& _rhs) : var(_rhs.var){cout << "Copy" << endl;}
    A(A&& _rhs) : var(std::move(_rhs.var)){cout << "Move" << endl;}
    int var;
};

void foo(std::shared_ptr<A> _a){
    _a->var = 43;
    cout << _a->var << endl;
}

int main() {
    A a;
    cout << a.var << endl;
    foo(std::make_shared<A>(std::move(a)));
    cout << a.var << endl;
    a.var = 44;
    foo(std::make_shared<A>(std::move(a)));
    cout << a.var << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

#### Output:

> Default 
>  42 
>  Move 
>  43 
>  42 
>  Move 
>  43 
>  44

Comment: @T.C.: You are correct. Some members are heap allocated. The whole idea is to steal the guts of `A`. I really don't care what happens to it after calling `foo`. I should have been more clear on that.

Comment: Do you know *why* the external API takes a `shared_ptr`? If not, whatever you do is very unlikely to work.

Comment: Then if you implement move semantics on `A` correctly, `make_shared` with `std::move` will just move the guts and should be quite cheap.

Comment: Can I shoot the person who put `shared_ptr` into an API for you?

Comment: You seem to discount `foo(std::make_shared<A>(std::move(a)));` since it makes a copy, but avoiding a copy isn't the goal.  Aquiring a `std::shared_ptr<A>` cheaply is the goal, which that code does.

Comment: @T.C. Good suggestion. I'll see what I can do on that front. There are some other good solns in this thread as well.

Comment: Wait, `A` is a 1 gb object **on the stack**?  I doubt it: it is probably a smaller object that owns 1 gb of data on the free store/heap, right?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is possible with the `shared_ptr` constructor  that allows for an "empty instance with non-null stored pointer":

```
A x;
std::shared_ptr<A> i_dont_own(std::shared_ptr<A>(), &x);
```

(It's "overload (8)" on the [cppreference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr&oldid=67367).)

Comment: The `template<class Y> shared_ptr(const shared_ptr<Y>& r, T *p) noexcept` constructor signature is available in C++11: it's detailed in [util.smartptr.shared.const]/13 through /16.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I've never seen this constructor before, it seems incredibly strange and dangerous

Comment: @MooingDuck: It *is* incredibly strange and dangerous. The OP is doing something incredibly strange and dangerous, and is probably feeling incredibly strange, too.

Comment: @MooingDuck It's meant to enable creation of e.g. a `shared_ptr` to a member of an object while sharing ownership of the object itself. Using it this way definitely qualifies as a hack ;)

Comment: @Casey: Ooooh, that makes more sense!

Comment: @KerrekSB Some days I feel so strange I don't know if I even want to wear socks.

Comment: @Casey: Right - the responsibility for the correctness of this use depends lies with the caller: The object pointed to by the raw pointer must live at least as long as the created shared pointer. This can be trivially achieved if the raw pointee is a subobject of the shared pointee, or by other means (as in the OP's case).

Comment: +1 This is butt-ugly code I could learn to love.  Unlike the null-deleter solution, this construction allocates no memory and is officially `noexcept`.  One quirk:  the client `foo`, if it bothers to check, is going to see `a.use_count() == 0`, even though `a.get()` returns the correct non-null pointer.

Answer (score 7):

If you know that shared pointer you pass to `foo()` will not get stored, copied etc, ie will not outlive your object you can make `std::shared_ptr` pointed to object on the stack with empty deleter:

```
void emptyDeleter( A * ) {}

A a;
foo( std::shared_ptr<A>( &a, emptyDeleter ) );
```

Again you need to make sure that shared pointer or it's copy will not outlive the object and well document this hack.

Comment: It's hard to imagine a case where he can't change the interface but can make sure the pointer won't outlive the object.

Comment: Wouldn't that make it of a different type? OP cannot change the function signature, so this wouldn't work.

Comment: If the function takes a `shared_ptr`, that's usually because it stores a copy of the smart pointer somewhere and then returns, this solution is likely to cause undefined behavior.

Comment: @juanchopanza: No, `shared_ptr` type-erases the deleter.  That's only an issue with `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @juanchopanza no it would not

Comment: @DavidSchwartz it is not hard to imagine that instance of class A is created in `main()` and will outlive API, that requires shared_ptr. Anyway I think limitation of the solution is clear from the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming class `A` supports move semantics, do this:

```
std::shared_ptr<A> newA = make_shared<A> (std::move (_a));
```

Do not use `_a` anymore, use only `newA`. You can now pass `newA` to the function.

If class `A` does not support move semantics, there is no safe/sane way to do this. Any hack will only happen to work, and may break in the future. If you control enough of the class code, you may be able to add support for move semantics.

> But from what I can tell, a new instance of A is still created.

Why do you care? What you're trying to avoid is copying all *the data in the instance*, and this does that.

The point of move semantics is to *move* the data from one instance to another without having to do an allocate/copy/free. Of course, this makes the original instance "empty", so don't use that anymore.