# shared_ptr throw error: pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: c++, c++11, malloc, shared-ptr

```
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

shared_ptr<int> tmpfunc1(int* p)
{
    return shared_ptr<int>(p);
}

void tmpfunc2(int * px)
{
    shared_ptr<int> ptr1 = tmpfunc1(px);
}

int main()
{   
    int x = 1;
    tmpfunc2(&x);   
    return 0;
}
```

The following code would abort before tmpfunc2() returns (and when ptr1 is destroyed). Can anybody explain what is happening? I think the temporary object returned from tmpfunc1 is causing the problem, but cannot figure out why.

What would be a best practice to return shared_ptr?

Thanks!

Updates:

Thanks for the reply everyone. I was doing this because recently I was working on a code base that was implemented in the following way (a minimal example):

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

shared_ptr<int> tmpfunc1(int* p)
{
    return shared_ptr<int>(p);
}

void tmpfunc2(int * px)
{
    shared_ptr<int> ptr1 = tmpfunc1(px);
}


class A
{
public:
    vector<int*> ptrvec;
    vector<shared_ptr<int> > shrptrvec;
    A() {};
    ~A() {};
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        shared_ptr<int> tmpptr(new int);
        a.ptrvec.push_back(tmpptr.get());
        a.shrptrvec.push_back(tmpptr);
    }
    tmpfunc2(a.ptrvec[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

This code will still fail, probably because by providing only a.ptrvec[0] the temporary shared_ptr has no info of existing counter and will make all shared_ptr in a.shrptrvec points to invalid position.

Am I correct?

Again, thanks for everyone.

Comment: x is created on the stack. The destructor of ptr1 calls delete which is only allowed for objects that were created with new.

Comment: **Never** pass a pointer to `shared_ptr` that isn't allocated through `new`!

Comment: Even better, stay away from `new` and stick to `make_shared` wherever possible.

Comment: @ParkYoung-Bae: Except for [when you do](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24741131/596781)...

Answer (score 3):

Shared_ptr works with dynamic allocation ONLY! It cannot free stack allocated resource.

```
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

shared_ptr<int> tmpfunc1(int* p)
{
    return shared_ptr<int>(p);
}

void tmpfunc2(int * px)
{
    shared_ptr<int> ptr1 = tmpfunc1(px);
}

int main()
{   
    int* x = new int(1);
    tmpfunc2(x);

    return 0;
}
```

Probably better solution

```
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

void tmpfunc(int px)
{
    shared_ptr<int> ptr1 = make_shared(px);
}

int main()
{   
    int x(1);
    tmpfunc(x);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what if the user provides a deleter which does NOTHING? (isn't this case though).

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Dynamic allocation is usefull to extend the scope of the variable. If you use your solution the variable will be out of scope before the shared_ptr is destroyed and you keep a shared_ptr with en invalid state. If it is not the case, then you don't need a shared_ptr.

Comment: My comment isn't a solution, it's only a guess: if an empty deleter is provided then *maybe* the error doesn't rise. But as a guess, isn't a solution at all (even if it isn't a guess, it cannot be considered as a solution I think).

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Sorry, by "solution" i meant "if you use this". If you do not attempt to delete the pointer the error is not triggered, you're right. But this is still undefined behavior.