# What is the difference between an empty and a null std::shared_ptr in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

The [cplusplus.com `shared_ptr` page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/) calls out a distinction between an *empty* `std::shared_ptr` and a *null* `shared_ptr`. The [cppreference.com page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) doesn't explicitly call out the distinction, but uses both "empty" and comparison to `nullptr` in its description of `std::shared_ptr` behavior.

Is there a difference between an empty and a null `shared_ptr`? Is there any use case for such mixed-behavior pointers? Does a non-empty null `shared_ptr` even make sense? Would there ever be a case in normal usage (i.e. if you didn't explicitly construct one) where you could end up with an empty-but-non-null `shared_ptr`?

And do any of these answers change if you're using the Boost version instead of the C++11 version?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

It's a weird corner of `shared_ptr` behavior. It has a constructor that allows you to make a `shared_ptr` that *owns* something and *points to* something else:

```
template< class Y > 
shared_ptr( const shared_ptr<Y>& r, T *ptr );
```

The `shared_ptr` constructed using this constructor *shares ownership* with `r`, but *points to* whatever `ptr` points to (i.e., calling `get()` or `operator->()` will return `ptr`). This is handy for cases where `ptr` points to a subobject (e.g., a data member) of the object owned by `r`.

The page you linked calls a `shared_ptr` that owns nothing *empty*, and a `shared_ptr` that points to nothing (i.e., whose `get() == nullptr`) *null*. (*Empty* is used in this sense by the standard; *null* isn't.) You can construct a null-but-not-empty `shared_ptr`, but it won't be very useful. An empty-but-not-null `shared_ptr` is essentially a non-owning pointer, which can be used to do some weird things like [passing a pointer to something allocated on the stack to a function expecting a `shared_ptr`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24741061/how-to-avoid-big-memory-allocation-with-stdmake-shared/24741131#24741131) (but I'd suggest punching whoever put `shared_ptr` inside the API first).

`boost::shared_ptr` also [has this constructor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#aliasing_constructor), which they call the *aliasing constructor*.

Comment: Worth noting: **C++11 § 20.7.2.2.1 (p16)** "Note: This constructor allows creation of an empty `shared_ptr` instance with a non-NULL stored pointer." Also worth mentioning the preceding note (p15), "To avoid the possibility of a dangling pointer, the user of this constructor must ensure that `p` remains valid at least until the ownership group of `r` is destroyed." A rarely used construction indeed.

Comment: @Cubbi A `shared_ptr` whose `get()` returns `nullptr` *does* compare equal to `nullptr` regardless of whether it owns anything.

Comment: A null-but-nonempty `shared_ptr`s *can* be useful, to make sure some function gets executed once all owning pointers run out of scope (even in case of an exception!). Not sure, whether there is now a special class for this.

Comment: @coldfix What can a null-but-nonempty `shared_ptr` do that a non-null-and-nonempty `shared_ptr` can't?

Comment: @T.C. you can use it to call a function with a null pointer as first argument:P. Also if you only care about some function (or lambda) getting executed at specific time and don't know any object to pass to it, you would use null to make that explicit. I admit, using a dedicated class without pointer functionality would be even more explicit and better, but also more work for small projects;). See [Using shared_ptr to execute code on block exit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/smart_ptr/sp_techniques.html#on_block_exit)

Comment: @coldfix It appears to me that while you can create a null-but-nonempty shared pointer, it must piggy back on a nonnull nonempty to get its reference count.  Or does passing a non-`nullptr` null to `shared_ptr` create a reference counting block?

Comment: @Yakk It seems that passing along a custom deleter (or a non-nullptr null) is sufficient to cause a reference counting block to be created, given the way the spec is written.

Comment: The aliasing constructor originates from Bloomberg and was proposed for the standard before it was implemented in Boost (see [N1851](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/SC22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1851.pdf)). I prefer the standard's term "shares ownership with `r`" to the phrasing "owns whatever `r` owns"

Comment: @JonathanWakely tweaked. I'm really just citing boost for the name "aliasing constructor", since it's not found in the standard.

Answer (score 12):

*Is there a difference between an empty and a null shared_ptr?*

Empty `shared_ptr` doesn't have control block and its use count considered to be 0. Copy of empty `shared_ptr` is another empty `shared_ptr`. They are both separate `shared_ptr`s that doesn't share common control block because they don't have it. Empty `shared_ptr` can be constructed with default constructor or with constructor that takes `nullptr`.

Non-empty null `shared_ptr` has control block that can be shared with other `shared_ptr`s. Copy of non-empty null `shared_ptr` is `shared_ptr` that shares the same control block as original `shared_ptr` so use count is not 0. **It can be said that all copies of `shared_ptr` share the same `nullptr`**. Non-empty null `shared_ptr` can be constructed with null pointer of object's type (not `nullptr`)

Here is example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "std::shared_ptr<int> ptr1:" << std::endl;
    {
        std::shared_ptr<int> ptr1;
        std::cout << "\tuse count before copying ptr: " << ptr1.use_count() << std::endl;
        std::shared_ptr<int> ptr2 = ptr1;
        std::cout << "\tuse count  after copying ptr: " << ptr1.use_count() << std::endl;        
        std::cout << "\tptr1 is " << (ptr1 ? "not null" : "null") << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "std::shared_ptr<int> ptr1(nullptr):" << std::endl;
    {
        std::shared_ptr<int> ptr1(nullptr);
        std::cout << "\tuse count before copying ptr: " << ptr1.use_count() << std::endl;
        std::shared_ptr<int> ptr2 = ptr1;
        std::cout << "\tuse count  after copying ptr: " << ptr1.use_count() << std::endl;        
        std::cout << "\tptr1 is " << (ptr1 ? "not null" : "null") << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "std::shared_ptr<int> ptr1(static_cast<int*>(nullptr))" << std::endl;
    {
        std::shared_ptr<int> ptr1(static_cast<int*>(nullptr));
        std::cout << "\tuse count before copying ptr: " << ptr1.use_count() << std::endl;
        std::shared_ptr<int> ptr2 = ptr1;
        std::cout << "\tuse count  after copying ptr: " << ptr1.use_count() << std::endl;        
        std::cout << "\tptr1 is " << (ptr1 ? "not null" : "null") << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It outputs:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> ptr1:
    use count before copying ptr: 0
    use count  after copying ptr: 0
    ptr1 is null

std::shared_ptr<int> ptr1(nullptr):
    use count before copying ptr: 0
    use count  after copying ptr: 0
    ptr1 is null

std::shared_ptr<int> ptr1(static_cast<int*>(nullptr))
    use count before copying ptr: 1
    use count  after copying ptr: 2
    ptr1 is null
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/54f59730905ed2ff

Comment: I think this better answers why we have to check for null in custom deleter of shared_ptr. [Does it make sense to check for nullptr in custom deleter of shared_ptr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42962515/does-it-make-sense-to-check-for-nullptr-in-custom-deleter-of-shared-ptr/42962962)