# Easier way to have shared_ptr own an existing pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, memory, memory-management, shared-ptr

Many programmers advocate the use of `make_shared` because it reduces typing and reduces programming errors. However there are some cases where using the constructors of `shared_ptr` is unavoidable. One of these cases is when you have an existing pointer that you want `shared_ptr` to own, since `shared_ptr<Foo>(&existing_ptr)` is bad code. Instead, you have to use the unwieldy `shared_ptr<Foo>(shared_ptr<Foo>(), p)`. Not only are you repeating yourself, but you have to create a temporary object.

```
int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    Foo foo;
    foo.n = 1;
    {
        auto ptr = make_shared<Foo>(move(foo));
        ptr->n = 42;
        cout << ptr->n << " " << foo.n << '\n';
    }
    {
        auto p = &foo;
        auto ptr = shared_ptr<Foo>(shared_ptr<Foo>(), p);
        ptr->n = 42;
        cout << ptr->n << " " << foo.n << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
Foo::Foo()
Foo::Foo(Foo &&)
42 1
Foo::~Foo()
42 42
Foo::~Foo()
```

What's a less verbose way to have `shared_ptr` own an existing pointer?

Comment: `&existing_ptr` is clearly wrong -- you mean `&existing_object`.

Comment: `shared_ptr<Foo>(&existing_ptr)` is simply incorrect, but what's so wrong with `shared_ptr<Foo>(existing_ptr)`?

Comment: @n.m. in this case the `shared_ptr` would try to delete the pointer on destruction, which will fail because the pointer doesn't point to an object allocated with `new`.

Comment: @MMarkRansom What's the point of wanting a shared_ptr for something that cannot be deleted?

Comment: @n.m. unfortunately some people have gotten into the habit of using it in their function signatures, forcing you to use it even when it's not appropriate.

Answer (score 6):

The intended use of that constructor is to allow shared pointers to sub objects of shared pointers.

Your use is not the intended use, and is quite dangerous, as you have implicitly created a guarantee that the data you are passing to the shared pointer will last as long as the shared pointer or its copies does, and then failing to enforce that guarantee in any meaningful sense.

If you pass a shared pointer to a function, it has every right to cache a copy if it and use it 15 minutes later.  And if you aren't passing a shared pointer to a function, you don't need one.

In general, a function should only require a shared pointer if it intends to extend the lifetime of its argument in a difficult to predict way.  So if you have a function that takes a shared pointer and never extends its lifetime (or the lifetime of a pointer to it), it should not be taking a shared pointer.  The problem is in the function you are calling, not with how you have to jump through hoops to call it.

Only when you both have a function that is broken, **and** are unable to fix it **and** making a copy of `Foo` on the free store is overly expensive, is your technique worth trying.  And that should be extreme corner cases anyhow.

Comment: I agree, doesn't make too much sense either

Answer (score 2):

IMO what you're doing there *shouldn't* be easy because it's very dangerous, and only necessary under highly specialized circumstances where typing a class name twice should be the least of your worries.

But here is a slightly more succinct way to achieve the same thing by using a dummy deleter:

```
auto ptr = std::shared_ptr<Foo>(&foo, [](void*){});
```

Also, in your approach it isn't really correct to say that `ptr` *owns* `foo`; rather it owns the null object in the empty `std::shared_ptr<Foo>` and *points to* `foo` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25920775/3549027) for a longer discussion). In my code above it does "own" `foo` in some technical sense (or at least it thinks it does); it's just been prevented from doing anything to it when its reference count reaches zero.