# Stored-by-Value Pool that support polymorphism, how to use smart pointer?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, smart-pointers, pool

### Introduction

I have a data structure : pool of values.   (not pool of pointers)

When I called **create()**, it will return **Handle**.

Everything is good so far.

```
template<class T> class Pool{
    std::vector<T> v;                   //store by value
    Handle<T> create(){  .... }
}
template<class T> class Handle{
    Pool<T>* pool_;                    //pointer back to container
    int pool_index_;                   //where I am in the container
    T* operator->() {                  
        return pool_->v.at(pool_index_);     //i.e. "pool[index]"
    }
    void destroy(){
        pool_-> ... destroy(this)  .... mark "pool_index_" as unused, etc ....
    }
}
```

Now I want **Handle<>** to support polymorphism.

### Question

Many experts have kindly advised me to use **weak_ptr**, but I still have been left in blank for a week, don't know how to do it.

The major parts that I stuck are :-

- Should **create()** return **weak_ptr**, not **Handle**?
     .... or should **Handle** encapsulate **weak_ptr**?
- If **create()** return **weak_ptr** for user's program, ...
  how **weak_ptr** would know ***pool_index_***?  It doesn't have such field.
- If the user cast **weak_ptr**/**Handle** to a parent class pointer as followed, there are many issues :-

e.g.

```
class B{}

class C : public B { ......
}
....
{
    Pool<C> cs;
    Handle<C> cPtr=cs.create();
    Handle<B> bPtr=cPtr;     // casting ;expected to be valid, 
                             //       ... but how? (weak_ptr may solve it)
    bPtr->destroy()   ;      // aPtr will invoke Pool<B>::destroy  which is wrong!
                             //     Pool<C>::destroy is the correct one
    bPtr.operator->() ;      // face the same problem as above
}
```

### Assumption

- Pool is always deleted after Handle (for simplicity).
- no multi-threading

Here are similar questions, but none are close enough.
[C++ object-pool that provides items as smart-pointers that are returned to pool upon deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27827923/c-object-pool-that-provides-items-as-smart-pointers-that-are-returned-to-pool)
[C++11 memory pool design pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16378306/c11-memory-pool-design-pattern)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Regarding `weak_ptr`

A `std::weak_ptr` is always associated with a `std::shared_ptr`. To use `weak_ptr` you would have to manage your objects with `shared_ptr`. This would mean ownership of your objects can be shared: Anybody can construct a `shared_ptr` from a `weak_ptr` and store it somewhere. The pointed-to object will only get deleted when all `shared_ptr`'s are destroyed. The `Pool` will lose direct control over object deallocation and thus cannot support a public `destroy()` function.
With shared ownership things can get really messy.

This is one reason why `std::unique_ptr` often is a better alternative for object lifetime management (sadly it doesn't work with `weak_ptr`). Your `Handle::destroy()` function also implies that this is not what you want and that the `Pool` alone should handle the lifetime of its objects.

However, `shared_ptr`/`weak_ptr` are designed for multi-threaded applications. In a single-threaded environment you can get `weak_ptr`-like functionality (check for valid targets and avoid dangling pointers) without using `weak_ptr` at all:

```
template<class T> class Pool {
    bool isAlive(int index) const { ... }
}

template<class T> class Handle {
    explicit operator bool() const { return pool_->isAlive(pool_index_); }
}
```

#### Why does this only work in a single-threaded environment?

Consider this scenario in a **multi-threaded** program:

```
void doSomething(std::weak_ptr<Obj> weak) {
    std::shared_ptr<Obj> shared = weak.lock();
    if(shared) {
        // Another thread might destroy the object right here
        // if we didn't have our own shared_ptr<Obj> 
        shared->doIt(); // And this would crash
    }
}
```

In the above case, we have to make sure that the pointed-to object is still accessible after the `if()`. We therefore construct a `shared_ptr` that will keep it alive - no matter what.

In a **single-threaded** program you don't have to worry about that:

```
void doSomething(Handle<Obj> handle) {
    if(handle) {
        // No other threads can interfere
        handle->doIt();
    }
}
```

You still have to be careful when dereferencing the handle multiple times. Example:

```
void doDamage(Handle<GameUnit> source, Handle<GameUnit> target) {    
    if(source && target) {
        source->invokeAction(target);
        // What if 'target' reflects some damage back and kills 'source'?
        source->payMana(); // Segfault
    }
}
```

But with another `if(source)` you can now easily check if the handle is still valid!

### Casting Handles

So, the template argument `T` as in `Handle<T>` doesn't necessarily match the type of the pool. Maybe you could resolve this with template magic. I can only come up with a solution that uses dynamic dispatch (virtual method calls):

```
struct PoolBase {
    virtual void destroy(int index)       = 0;
    virtual void* get(int index)          = 0;
    virtual bool isAlive(int index) const = 0;
};

template<class T> struct Pool : public PoolBase {
    Handle<T> create() { return Handle<T>(this, nextIndex); }
    void destroy(int index) override { ... }
    void* get(int index) override { ... }
    bool isAlive(int index) const override { ... }
};

template<class T> struct Handle {
    PoolBase* pool_;
    int pool_index_;

    Handle(PoolBase* pool, int index) : pool_(pool), pool_index_(index) {}

    // Conversion Constructor
    template<class D> Handle(const Handle<D>& orig) {
        T* Cannot_cast_Handle = (D*)nullptr;
        (void)Cannot_cast_Handle;

        pool_ = orig.pool_;
        pool_index_ = orig.pool_index_;
    }

    explicit operator bool() const { return pool_->isAlive(pool_index_); }
    T* operator->() { return static_cast<T*>( pool_->get(pool_index_) ); }
    void destroy() { pool_->destroy(pool_index_); }
};
```

Usage:

```
Pool<Impl> pool;
Handle<Impl> impl = pool.create();

// Conversions
Handle<Base> base  = impl; // Works
Handle<Impl> impl2 = base; // Compile error - which is expected
```

The lines that check for valid conversions are likely to be optimized out. The check will still happen at compile-time! Trying an invalid conversion will give you an error like this:

> error: invalid conversion from 'Base*' to 'Impl*' [-fpermissive]
>            T* Cannot_cast_Handle = (D*)nullptr;

I uploaded a simple, compilable test case here: http://ideone.com/xeEdj5