# Can a pointer move itself to a container?

Tags: c++, c++11

This is a continuation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27827923/c-object-pool-that-provides-items-as-smart-pointers-that-are-returned-to-pool) question but I don't want to use a custom deleter. I have the following interface:

```
struct Interface {
  Interface(const Interface &) = delete;
  auto operator=(const Interface &) -> Interface & = delete;
  ~Interface() = 0;
  protected:
    Interface() = default;
};
```

And an implementation:

```
struct Implementation : public Interface {
  Implementation(Pool &p) : m_pool{p} {}
  Pool &m_pool;
};
```

I also have a pool of Implementations:

```
struct Pool {
  auto get() -> std::unique_ptr<Interface>;
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Interface>> m_objects;
};
```

My question is if it is possible to have the `Implementation`, instantiated as a pointer to `Interface`, move itself into the pool when its destructor is called?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Added a link to a similar-ish question.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Edit: whoops, read it backwards once again. You're right, I got confused by the conflation of the pointer and the pointee.

Comment: Side-note (I suppose): what's that reference to `Pool` inside `Pool` itself?

Comment: Implementation has a reference to the Pool. When the destructor of Imp is called I want Imp to move itself into the pool.

Comment: FTFY :) -------

Comment: But if you move Implementation to Pool in the destructor (or after) your pointer will be invalid..

Comment: Which is ok because the object has left the scope anyway.

Comment: IMHO, it would be simpler to use a custom deleter in the `unique_ptr`. That way only the unique pointer has to be aware of the pool not the object itself.

Comment: But OTOH I'd have to provide an object with a custom deleter to the user.

Comment: You could achieve this using a class-specific `operator new` and `operator delete` that operate with the pool, but then you have to really delete the objects when the pool is destroyed.

Comment: Can you detail that @GemTaylor?

Comment: @ruipacheco Much as I would like the points, you are better off reading up about these methods for yourself, and decide if they are appropriate in your case.

Comment: @GemTaylor you don't have a specific idea on how it applies to my case?

Comment: With operator new and operator delete members in your class, any code that tries to new or delete an instance of your object calls your methods instead of the default methods, and your methods can interact with your pool.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ object-pool that provides items as smart-pointers that are returned to pool upon deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27827923/c-object-pool-that-provides-items-as-smart-pointers-that-are-returned-to-pool)

Comment: `~Interface() = 0;` doesn't compile.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat it's missing the virtual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can achieve it by creating a wrapper. It is kind of like borrowing an object from the pool which will then be put back into the pool once the wrapped object goes out of scope.

```
struct PooledObject {
  PooledObject(Pool& pool, std::unique_ptr<Interface> object) 
        : m_object(std::move(object)), m_pool(pool) {}
  ~PooledObject() {
       m_pool.put(std::move(m_object));
   }
  // implement -> for easy access to underlying object
  std::unique_ptr<Interface> m_object;
  Pool& m_pool;
};

struct Pool {
  auto get() -> PooledObject;
  void put(std::unique_ptr<Interface> object);
}
```

Comment: In that case it's better to use a custom deleter then?

Comment: @ruipacheco Maybe that will work, you will need to update the deleter before returning the object from the pool and then again before putting it back.

Comment: By deleted you mean the custom deleter?