# Is it correct to return null shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, weak-ptr

For example, there is a function that finds an object and returns shared_ptr if object is found, and must indicate somehow that no object was found.

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr> Storage::objects;

std::shared_ptr<Object> Storage::findObject()
{
  if (objects.find)
  {
    return objects[x];
  }
  else
  {
    return nullptr;
  }
}

std::shared_ptr<Object> obj = Storage::findObject();
if (obj)
{
  print("found");
}
else
{
  print("not found");
}
```

1. Is it correct to return shared_ptr implicitly initialized with nullptr like in upper example? It will work, but can be it done this way? Or should I return shared_ptr default constructed instead?
2. What in case it would be weak_ptr? What is proper way to check that empty weak_ptr has been returned? by weak_ptr::expired function or are there other ways? If checking by weak_ptr::expired is the only way then how can I distinguish that function returned empty pointer, or object was just deleted(multi-thread environment)?

Comment: an alternative would be to throw an exception

Comment: @AndersK. Situation when object is not found is as common situation as if object is found.

Comment: ok, then exception is not a good choice.

Comment: I think you've answered your own question then, John.

Comment: If you can use boost, `optional<T>` seems to be exactly what you want (this seems to be coming into the standard in C++17). If you don't want the overhead, then you basically just have to document that a `nullptr` is in fact an absence of value and not a mistake.

Comment: @Peter I don't understand, where I have answered my own question? I was asking if it is correct to return shared_ptr constructed with nullptr(pointing to nothing) or should I return empty(default constructed) pointer in situation object was not found.

Comment: If an error occurs in a function that needs to be reported to the caller, the broad choices of approach are either to return a value indicating an error, or to throw an exception.   In your comments, you have concluded that throwing an exception is not a good choice.  A `shared_ptr` can hold a `nullptr` so this is a valid choice.

Comment: @Peter But shouldn't it be empty shared_ptr(default constructed) instead of shared_ptr constructed with nullptr? I think there is difference between both.

Comment: @JohnLock: No, there is no difference.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley:   From (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/ )  -     "A shared_ptr that does not own any pointer is called an empty shared_ptr. A shared_ptr that points to no object is called a null shared_ptr and shall not be dereferenced. Notice though that an empty shared_ptr is not necessarily a null shared_ptr, and a null shared_ptr is not necessarily an empty shared_ptr."

Comment: @JohnLock: That's wrong.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley can you explain why it's wrong?

Comment: For `shared_ptr<>::shared_ptr()` (the default ctor), the standard's post conditions indicate that `use_count() == 0 && get() == nullptr`. Thus, if some implementation doesn't have those, it is wrong because it is not standard compliant. (20.10.2.2.1)

Comment: @JohnLock: I take it back. That paragraph is not wrong. However, your conclusion from it is wrong. A `shared_ptr` constructed from `nullptr` is the same as a default constructed `shared_ptr`. However, this may be different from a `shared_ptr` constructed with a typed null pointer (i.e. (Object*)0).

Comment: JohnLock, @BenjaminLindley . http://stackoverflow.com/q/25920681/5447906

Comment: Where is the type for the shared_ptr ? Shouldn't first line instead be:

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Object> > Storage::objects;

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> Is it correct to return shared_ptr implicitly initialized with nullptr like in upper example?

Yes, it is correct to initialize `shared_ptr` with `nullptr`. It is also correct to assign `nullptr` to `shared_ptr`.

> Or should I return shared_ptr default constructed instead?

You can do this in both ways:

1. returning `shared_ptr` initialized with `nullptr`

   ```
   return shared_ptr<Object>(nullptr);
   ```
2. returning `shared_ptr` default constructed.

   ```
   return shared_ptr<Object>();
   ```

Both ways are correct and both have the same effect. You can use whatever way you want.

> What in case it would be weak_ptr? What is proper way to check that empty weak_ptr has been returned? by weak_ptr::expired function or are there other ways?

`weak_ptr` becomes `nullptr` (expires) whenever the last `shared_ptr` associated with object is destroyed.

The proper way to work with `weak_ptr` is to convert it to `shared_ptr` with [lock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr/lock) method, and then to work with created `shared_ptr`. In that case your `weak_ptr` will no expire until you have that new `shared_ptr`. If you don't convert `weak_ptr` into `shared_ptr`, your `weak_ptr` may expire at any moment.

And yes, before working with newly created `shared_ptr`, you must check that it isn't null, because `weak_ptr` may had been expired before you created `shared_ptr` with `lock` method.

```
std::weak_ptr<Object> Storage::findObject();

...

std::weak_ptr  <Object> weak   = Storage::findObject();
std::shared_ptr<Object> shared = weak.lock();
if (shared) // check that weak was not expired when we did "shared = weak.lock()"
{
    // do something with shared, it will not expire.
}
```

Comment: I would not use `return shared_ptr<Object>(nullptr);` as `return shared_ptr<Object>();` is enough. It is a style preference: I don't write unnecessary stuff, as it might make think others that they are necessary. Sometime others might learn from what you write and could obtain misconceptions.