# Does it make sense to check for nullptr in custom deleter of shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I've seen some code that uses `std::shared_ptr` with a custom deleter that test the argument for nullptr, for example, `MyClass` which has a `close()` method and is constructed with some `CreateMyClass`:

```
auto pMyClass = std::shared_ptr<MyClass>(CreateMyClass(), 
                                        [](MyClass* ptr)
                                        { 
                                            if(ptr) 
                                                ptr->close(); 
                                        });
```

Does it make sense to test `ptr` for null-ness in the deleter? 
Can this happen? how?

Comment: Probably: _"Unlike std::unique_ptr, the deleter of std::shared_ptr is invoked even if the managed pointer is null."_ Source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/~shared_ptr

Comment: On one hand, putting that branch in `shared_ptr` means people would pay extra for it when using the default `delete ptr;`. On the other, this is probably overshadowed by the reference counting.

Comment: @RichardCritten, OK, but how can this occur?

Comment: it can occur if your `CreateMyClass()` returns a nullptr. Then shared_ptr dtor will call custom deleter and your check will make sense.

Comment: Irrelevant side-note: What little overhead that test involves would likely be made up for by using `std::make_shared` instead of the plain `std::shared_ptr` constructor (`std::make_shared` allocates both `shared_ptr` management structure and stored object as a single memory block, which the plain constructor can't do; reduces memory fragmentation and allocator overhead).

Comment: Except that make_shared can't take a custom creator/deleter

Comment: @ZivS: Oops, my bad. I guess that's what `std::allocate_shared` is for, though writing the allocator instead of just a deleter is a lot more work. Blech.

Comment: @ZivS Make shared cannot, but the thing you create *can* take a custom creator, then an aliasing constructor can switch back to the type you want to expose.  ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The constructor `std::shared_ptr<T>::shared_ptr(Y*p)` has the requirement that `delete p` is a valid operation. This is a valid operation when `p` equals `nullptr`.

The constructor `std::shared_ptr<T>::shared_ptr(Y*p, Del del)` has the requirement that `del(p)` is a valid operation.

If your custom deleter cannot handle `p` being equal to `nullptr` then it is not valid to pass a null `p` in the constructor of `shared_ptr`.

The constructor you offer as an example can be better presented, thus:

```
#include <memory>

struct MyClass {
    void open() {
        // note - may throw
    };

    void close() noexcept {
        // pre - is open
    }
};

struct Closer
{
    void operator()(MyClass* p) const noexcept
    {
        p->close();
        delete p;  // or return to pool, etc
    }
};

auto CreateMyClass() -> std::unique_ptr<MyClass, Closer>
{
    // first construct with normal deleter
    auto p1 = std::make_unique<MyClass>();

    // in case this throws an exception.
    p1->open();

    // now it's open, we need a more comprehensive deleter
    auto p = std::unique_ptr<MyClass, Closer> { p1.release(), Closer() };
    return p;
}

int main()
{
    auto sp = std::shared_ptr<MyClass>(CreateMyClass());
}
```

Note that it is now not possible for the shared_ptr to own a null object.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it makes sense actually. Suppose `CreateMyClass` returns `nullptr`. Reference count of `pMyClass` (`use_count`) becomes `1`. When `pMyClass` will be destroyed, [following will happens](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/~shared_ptr):

> If `*this` owns an object and it is the last `shared_ptr` owning it, the
>   object is destroyed through the owned deleter.

So if custom deleter dereferencing a pointer that holded by shared_ptr (`ptr->close()` in your code) then it should take care of nullptr checking.

Notice that [*empty shared_ptr* is not the same as *null shared_ptr*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25920681/what-is-the-difference-between-an-empty-and-a-null-stdshared-ptr-in-c).

Comment: I disagree. It doesn't matter if the pointer is `nullptr` or not. Delete has no effect on a `nullptr`. See Richard Hodges' answer.

Comment: @AndyG delete does not have effect on nullptr, but dereferencing holded pointer with accessing to its member (->close() in example) in custom deleter does. That's why custom deleter usually need, it does some work that delete cannot.

Comment: Ah, I glanced back at the example, and you're right. It's definitely doing something with the pointer before a call to `delete`. I retract my earlier statement.

Answer (score 2):

```
struct deleter {
  template<class T>
  void operator()(T*) const {
    std::cout << "deleter run\n";
  }
};

int main() {
  std::shared_ptr<int> bob((int*)0, deleter{});
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ad0c4cfce8663496).

This prints `"deleter run\n"`.  The deleter is indeed run.

The concept of *empty* and the concept of *owning a nullptr* are distinct concepts for `shared_ptr`.

`bob` is non-*empty*, yet `bob.get()==nullptr`.  When non-*empty*, the destructor is called.

```
int main() {
  int x;
  std::shared_ptr<int> alice( std::shared_ptr<int>{}, &x );
}
```

`alice` is *empty*, yet `alice.get() != nullptr`.  When `alice` goes out of scope, `delete &x` is *not* run (and in fact no destructor is run).

This can only be avoided if you never construct your shared pointer with a null pointer and a deleter.

One way to approach this is to first create a unique pointer with a custom deleter.

```
template<class Deleter, class T>
std::unique_ptr<T, Deleter> change_deleter( std::unique_ptr<T> up, Deleter&& deleter={} ) {
  return {up.release(), std::forward<Deleter>(deleter)};
}

struct close_and_delete_foo; // closes and deletes a foo

std::unique_ptr<foo, close_and_delete_foo> make_foo() {
  auto foo = std::make_unique<foo>();
  if (!foo->open()) return {};
  return change_deleter<close_and_delete_foo>(std::move(foo));
}
```

Unlike `shared_ptr`, `unique_ptr` cannot hold `nullptr` yet be "non-empty" (the standard doesn't use the term *empty* for `unique_ptr`, instead it talks about `.get()==nullptr`).

`unique_ptr` can be implicitly converted to a `shared_ptr`.  If it has `nullptr`, the resulting `shared_ptr` is *empty*, not just holding `nullptr`.  The destroyer of the `unique_ptr` is carried over to the `shared_ptr`.

---

The downside to all of these techniques is that the `shared_ptr` reference counting memory block is a separate allocation to the object's memory block.  Two allocations is worse than one.

But the `make_shared` constructor doesn't let you pass in a custom deleter.

If destroying your object cannot throw, you can use the aliasing constructor to be extremely careful:

```
// empty base optimization enabled:
template<class T, class D>
struct special_destroyed:D {
  std::optional<T> t;
  template<class...Ds>
  special_destroyed(
    Ds&&...ds
  ):
    D(std::forward<Ds>(ds)...)
  {}
  ~special_destroyed() {
     if (t)
       (*this)(std::addressof(*t));
  }
};
std::shared_ptr<MyClass> make_myclass() {
  auto r = std::make_shared< special_destroyed<MyClass, CloseMyClass> >();
  r->t.emplace();
  try {
    if (!r->t->open())
      return {};
  } catch(...) {
    r->t = std::nullopt;
    throw;
  }
  return {r, std::addressof(*r.t)};
}
```

Here we manage to use one block for destroyer and reference counting, while permitting a possibly failing `open` operation, and automatically `closing` only when the data is actually there.

Note that the destroyer should *only* close the `MyClass`, not delete it; deleting is handled by an outer destroyer in the `make_shared` wrapping the `special_destroyed`.

This uses C++17 for `std::optional`, but alternative `optional`s are available from `boost` and elsewhere.

---

A raw C++14 solution.  We create a crude `optional`:

```
template<class T, class D>
struct special_delete:D {
  using storage = typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>::type;
  storage data;
  bool b_created = false;
  template<class...Ts>
  void emplace(Ts&&...ts) {
    ::new( (void*)&data ) T(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
    b_created=true;
  }
  template<std::size_t...Is, class Tuple>
  void emplace_from_tuple( std::index_sequence<Is...>, Tuple&&tup ) {
    return emplace( std::get<Is>(std::forward<Tuple>(tup))... );
  }
  T* get() {
    if (b_created)
      return reinterpret_cast<T*>(&data);
    else
      return nullptr;
  }
  template<class...Ds>
  special_delete(Ds&&...ds):D(std::forward<Ds>(ds)...){}
  ~special_delete() {
    if (b_created)
    {
      (*this)( get() );
      get()->~T();
    }
  }
};
struct do_nothing {
  template<class...Ts>
  void operator()(Ts&&...)const{}
};

template<class T, class D, class F=do_nothing, class Tuple=std::tuple<>, class...Ds>
std::shared_ptr<T> make_special_delete(
  F&& f={},
  Tuple&& args=std::tuple<>(),
  Ds&&...ds
) {
  auto r = std::make_shared<special_delete<T,D>>(std::forward<Ds>(ds)...);
  r->emplace_from_tuple(
    std::make_index_sequence<
      std::tuple_size<std::remove_reference_t<Tuple>>::value
    >{},
    std::move(args)
  );
  try {
    f(*r->get());
  } catch(...) {
    r->b_created = false;
    r->get()->~T();
    throw;
  }
  return {r, r->get()};
}
```

This is probably going too far.  Luckily our extremely limited `optional` can be written easier than a real `optional`, but I'm not certain I did it all right.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2129c72b0c267943).

The C++11 version requires manually writing `make_index_sequence` etc.

Comment: Can you clear the state `unique_ptr can be implicitly converted to a unique_ptr`? Or did you mean `to shared_ptr`?